# Losing CSS in content script

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, colorbox

I'm using colorbox plugin to create a modal dialog in certain pages. The dialog is created,  but I lose all borders / background overlay of my CSS... In the google chrome console I get errors like:

> https://www.website.com/br/cgi-bin/images/controls.png [404
> not found]
>
> https://www.website.com/br/cgi-bin/images/border.png [404
> not found]

While the files 'controls.png' and 'border.png' are in the local directory of the extension/css...

I'm injecting the CSS over content_script of Google Chrome Extension. Manifest:

```
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "css": ["colorbox.css"],
    "js": ["jquery.min.js", "jquery.colorbox.js", "dominteract.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": true
  }],
```

I note that in the CSS source code the images are linked this way:

> cboxOverlay{background:url(images/overlay.png) repeat 0 0;}

How can I declare this directory to the chrome's extension know this is a local directory and not a remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link your image you have to include your extension's directory, like this:

```
background:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/overlay.png') repeat 0 0;
```

You might need to add your image in your manifest as a web_accessible_resource like this:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/overlay.png"
]
```

Comment: I edited my question, anyway I think you already figured out the problem... I'm trying to update now for your solution, if works I accept your answer. Be right back.